# In Swift, URLSession.shared.dataTask sometimes work and sometimes not

Tags: node.js, swift, http

client: swift, xcode 8.3

server: nodejs, express, mongodb

In client side, it first send login request (username & password) to server, upon receive a valid token, it proceeds to the next screen to send another request to get a list of books.

The strange point is that, for the second request for books, sometimes it works - if with debug mode and a number of breakpoints proceeding "slowly", while sometimes it does not work - if proceed the breakpoints not such slow or without them. I repeated a number of times and figured out this pattern.

Here is the piece of code which send request - millions of thanks!!!

```
let url = URL(string: "http://" + SERVER_IP + ":" + PORT + "/books")
print("Query:>> url: ")
print(url)

var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
request.httpMethod = "GET"

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {(data, response, error) in
    print("Query>> response from loadBooks")
    if let data = data,
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])  {
        var books = [Book]()
        if let array = json as? [Any] {
            for i in 0...array.count-1 {
                var bookJson = array[i] as? [String: Any]
                let b = Book(json: bookJson!)
                books.append(b!)
            }
        }
        print ("Query>> \(books.count)" + " books loaded, callback completion")
        completion(books)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Console output when the request is not successful:

> Query:>> url: Optional(localhost:3001/books)
>
> 2017-09-07 15:31:45.173596+0800 SimplyRead[76273:2379182] [] nw_endpoint_flow_service_writes [1.1 ::1.3001 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Write request has 4294967295 frame count, 0 byte count Query>> response from loadBooks
>
> 2017-09-07 15:51:41.210732+0800 SimplyRead[76273:2390856] [] tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled

Comment: what kind of error do you get ? Is it unathorized 401 ?

Comment: Seems not, the server side actually have not enabled authorization yet. Here is from xcode log:

Query:>> url: 
Optional(http://localhost:3001/books)
2017-09-07 15:31:45.173596+0800 SimplyRead[76273:2379182] [] nw_endpoint_flow_service_writes [1.1 ::1.3001 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Write request has 4294967295 frame count, 0 byte count
Query>> response from loadBooks
2017-09-07 15:51:41.210732+0800 SimplyRead[76273:2390856] [] tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled

Comment: Try increasing the timeout interval to 60 seconds, I think second time is just slow.

Comment: It was 60s by default. I manually set it anyway by doing "request.timeoutInterval = 60.0", but with no luck.

Comment: Changed to use Alamofire which works fine with no such issues